# Is Flash (Flash/Flex/AIR) a still maintained technology (either officially / 3rd party) suitable for Web Player (linux) and mobiles?

Tags: flash, linux, flex

Today I use Flash Player 11 since it's the last one released by Adobe, for linux-based OSs. The same applies to Flex/AIR platforms: I use Flex 4.1.4 and AIR 2.6, while Windows and Mac systems have newer versions (at least 4.6 and 3.1 respectively).

Is there a (trusted 3rd party) community making a good port (*good* stands for compatibility) of those newer versions to Linux-based OSs? Or is Flash/Flex/AS3 actually dying*?

(* my concern with this point is that I would not like to stick to an unmaintained technology in a mid-term future. Currently I'm learning Citrus Engine + Starling and I'd like to know if it is a bad).

Comment: As a Linux user for 20 years, I don’t even think Flash has had a *present* on Linux. It’s always been lagging terribly behind the Windows port in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

I'll interpret your question this way:

> In the context where I want to *produce* stuff, should I keep on making games with Flash given the current situation?

From experience, if the publisher of an API or library stops supporting that said API/library, you'll be fine for some time, then it's going to start to be harder to work with the API as new OS will require new API binaries, access to core OS functions will change, and such.

That is, if the source is not released.

If the source is released, yes, a community can emerge and keep the support for the API, but development will most likely be halted or very slow, just like the bug fixes.

IMHO, if a technology has reached it's end of life, there is no point in putting time in it, and you'll have a better future to chose the technology that replaced it.

Comment: Which technology is a good replacement for Flex? I would not like to fall back to HTML5 since in my continuous experience playing those games, I see them as pretty slow.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Unfortunately, I don't have a suggestion for a replacement. And this would be out of the scope for this site :)